# Show that $\sum u_n$ converges for some $p > 1$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^p u_n = A < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We know from the integral test that $1/n^p$ converges for $p > 1$, which looks like something of use here, I think I could just do with a point in the right direction as to where to go from here... Thanks!

Comment: Use the definition of limit, and remember that what makes a series convergent is the "tail" of it

Comment: This means that $|u_n|\sim\frac{|A|}{n^p}$ if $A\neq 0$ and $u_n=o\left(\frac{1}{n^p}\right)$ if $A=0$.

Comment: Ah yes of course, it looks like $A/n^p$ for large enough $n$ which clearly converges. Cheers